# How Can I Understand Laravel Error Messages?

Tags: laravel, forms, validation, message

I read error messages in Laravel and how to do it, but I can't understand the steps. Please explain to me the whole code step by step.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OeW4r.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$error` variable is part of the request validation process in Laravel. You can read the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation) to get a quick introduction.

If the validation of a request fails this variable is available in all of your blade views. It’s an instance of the `Illuminate\Support\MessageBag` class. You can read more about working with error message [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#working-with-error-messages).